# Search char and insert new char after that char from string without loop

Tags: java, string

I want to search a particular char from string without any loop and then i want to insert new char after that.

```
String a = "my%name%is%";
```

I want to find `"%"` and then i want to insert "?" char.

***Output result:***

```
a = "my%?name%?is%?";
```

Comment: You can't do this reasonably without looping. Any other function you could use to do this will most likely loop internally.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace(char a,char b)`.

```
void replaceString(){
   String a = "my%name%is%";
   System.out.printlnt(a.replace("%","%?"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`

```
String a = "my%name%is%";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("([.*^%])", "%?"));//prints my%?name%?is%?
```